# Google maps android v2 xml file error message

Tags: android, xml, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to work with google maps for android v2. I followed the instructions from:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

I'm at the bottom (of the above webpage) where it says "Add a Map". When I copy and paste the following code into my main.xml:

```
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/map"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

I am greeted by an error on the Linearlayout tag that says: "The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed."

Here is main.xml in its entirety:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/map"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>


 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:padding="30dip">



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dip"
        android:text="@string/welcome"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" 
        android:hint="@string/edit_location"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/find_me_button"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_find_me"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

WHY is this not well-formed?

edit: I've tried deleting "xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" from LinearLayout but it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: You  fix this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:padding="30dip">

 <fragment
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dip"
    android:text="@string/welcome"
    android:textSize="24sp"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" 
    android:hint="@string/edit_location"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/find_me_button"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_find_me"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

It may help you.